# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: how to get contents of the parent div containing <h1> tags?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom, simpledom

I'm scraping (using PHP simple HTML DOM) a number of different (news) sites with the aim of getting the main content/body of text on the page.

To do this the best way i could figure out was to find the main header/headline (H1) and to get the text contained within the same div as this header tag.

How would i go about getting the contents of the whole (parent?) div, in both examples below.

```
<div>  <----- need to get contents of this whole div (containing the h1 and likely the main body of text)
  <h1></h1>
  main body of text here
</div>
```

Div maybe be further up the tree.

```
<div> <----- need to get contents of this whole div
  <div>   
    <h1></h1>
  </div>

  <div>
    main body of text here
  </div>
</div>
```

Div even further up the tree.

```
<div> <----- need to get contents of this whole div
  <div>

    <div>   
      <h1></h1>
    </div>

    <div>
      main body of text here
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Then i could compare the size of each, and determine the main div.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're using this? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @slapyo yes using simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Comment: PS: there is no such html element as `<text>`.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare the size of each, and determine the main div"? Have you thought about how you're going to *programmatically* determine which `div` is the "main" `div`?

Comment: You want the highest gparent div? In jQuery and [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/) it's the first `$('div:has(h1)')`. Simple can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $e contains the H1 element that you selected. You can call $e->parent() to grab the parent element.

Look under "How to traverse the DOM tree?" on the "Traverse the DOM tree" tab. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Answer (score 5):

You can use `parent` to get the parent element of the `h1`:

```
# assuming that the <h1> element is the first <h1> on the page:
$div = $html->find('h1', 0)->parent();
```